# How to update view based on check box clicked?

Tags: angular, angular-changedetection

I am trying to implement filters for different products by using json object.

Expected Output: I need that when filter check box is clicked the product list should shrink to the filtered products

Actual output: Filtered products are added to the existing product list

I have written logic to filter the products and it is getting filtered but while updating View it is added to existing list of products.

````
```/*---Service call for fetching category details by passing categoryId--- */
----Type Script code----
  getCategoryDetailsById(categoryId: Number) {
    this.categoryService.getCategoryDetailsById(categoryId).subscribe(resp => {
      this.categorySearchDetails = resp as CategorySearchDetails;

       this.categorySearchDetails.products.forEach(products => {

          products.images.forEach(images => {
          if (images.imageType === "productMainImage") {
            this.mainImgList.push(images.imageURL)
          }
          else if (images.imageType === "productHoverImage") {
            this.hoverImgList.push(images.imageURL)
          }
        })
      });
    });
  }

/*---iterating list from json object when check box is clicked--- */
  onToggle(event: any) {

 this.categorySearchDetails.products.forEach(resp => {
      resp.productCategoryAttribute.forEach(resp1 => {
        this.attributeValue = resp1.categoryAttributeValues[0].value
        resp.images.filter(element => {
          if (element.productId === resp.productId && event === this.attributeValue) {
            if (element.imageType === "productMainImage") {
              this.mainImgList.push(element.imageURL);

            }
            else if (element.imageType === "productHoverImage") {

              this.hoverImgList.push(element.imageURL)
          )
            }
          }
        });
      });
    });
  }

-----Html Code-------

 <ng-container *ngFor="let filters of filtersList">
           <div class="breakLine">
             <mat-checkbox *ngFor="let values of filters.categoryAttributeValues"(change)="onToggle(values.attributeValue)">{{values.attributeValue}}<br/>
             </mat-checkbox> 
            </div> <br>
  </ng-container> 

        <!-- Dynamic Product Grid  -->
        <form >
         <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-12 col-xl-3"*ngFor="let mainImage of mainImgList;let i=index; ">
           <div routerLink="/product/{{productId[i]}}">
                <img class="pic-1"   [src]="mainImage">
                 <img class="pic-2"  [src]="hoverImgList[i]">
            </div>
         </div>
        </form>
````

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], there is so many props that seem unnecessary. A minimal reproduction will increase your chances to get an answer :)

Answer (score 1):

In your sample code, you don't seem to clear out `mainImgList` ever.

One approach would be to create separate variables for `filteredImgList` and `mainImgList`.

Initially, `filteredImgList` will contain all the items in `mainImgList`.
On filter click, `filteredImgList` needs to be cleared out and then requery `mainImgList` to find out valid images.

```
/*---Service call for fetching category details by passing categoryId--- */
this.mainImgList = [];
this.filteredImgList= [];

//after service call in subscribe method
this.filteredImgList = this.mainImgList;


//after toggle
this.filteredImgList = this.mainImgList.filter(()=> /*some condition*/);
```

and bind your html to `filteredImgList` instead

Comment: But i want to show mainImageList on load. After that if user clicks on filter, filtered images should replace the existing ones

Comment: That is exactly what will happen in the above code. During initial load, `mainImgList` and `filteredImgList` will have same data, So if your UI is binded to `filteredImgList` it will still show all the data. Once the user clicks on filter, `filteredList` will requery the `mainImgList` to show the filtered result. The reason for having a separate variable is to make sure when user clicks on filtering more than once, you'll have a `mainImgList` from which you can query again.